# indexoutofrangeexception after january 2016 windows 10 updates

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am getting indexoutofrangeexception after january 2016 windows 10 update on one of my .net apps.  The application was working perfect before the update.  Did a system restore and application started working again.  Then did the windows 10 updates for january 2016 again and application stops running again.  Anybody else running into this issue with windows 10?

**Update #1**
Dns.GetHostEntry is the culprit, it was broken by jan 2016 windows 10 updates.  More details coming soon.

**Update # 2**
Found it!!!  ipv6 address returns as ::1 from Dns.GetHostEntry and breaks code!  I hope someone at microsoft is reading this.  This only occurs after the jan 2016 windows updates.  Also confirmed happening in windows 7.

Comment: Does this break .NET code, or your code? Code that presumably *"works perfectly"* occasionally is just lucky. And when an update comes along, it runs out of luck, and the program starts throwing up on what never was correct code.

Comment: To answer your question, it breaks .NET code since the ipv6 address is no longer returned and instead it returns ::1.

Comment: Whether you like it or not, this is documented behavior. See [Dns.GetHostEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx). Sounds like your application is not prepared to deal with errors, that didn't surface until the january 2016 update changed the environment your application is running in.

Comment: Coming from a company such as ms, I am not surprised.

Comment: Again, this is a bug in **your** application, not Microsoft's library. You were lucky and the bug never surfaced, until Microsoft deployed the January 2016 update. Fix your code.

Comment: Again, I am not surprise ms broke their library.  "Fix your code"? That is not of your concern how I choose to proceed.  Fix your attitude.

Comment: You still don't seem to get it: Microsoft didn't break their library. It is **your** code, that happened to work, by pure coincidence, and just ran out of luck. It was relying on undocumented behavior, and Microsoft rightfully changed that. The contract didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!!! ipv6 address returns as ::1 from Dns.GetHostEntry and breaks code! I hope someone at microsoft is reading this. This only occurs after the jan 2016 windows updates. Also confirmed happening in windows 7.